# Returning value of a clicked list item using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating a list of items from some JSON and i'm trying to get the 'data-value' of that item when it's clicked.  So far i have

```
 var target = $('#list');
 target.empty();
 for (var i = 0; i < myJson.length; i++) {
     $('<tr class = "selectedItem">')
         .append($('<td>', {
             'text': myJson[i].id,
             'data-value':myJson[i].id
         }))
         .append($('<td>', {
             'text': myJson[i].name
         }))
         .append($('<td>', {
             'text': myJson[i].Details
         }))
     .appendTo(target);
 };
```

Which builds a list and displays it in on the screen.  However when the user clicks one of these items i'm trying to get the id.  I added the "selectedItem" class thinking i would be able to just do a on click event but no such luck.  Here's what i have:

```
  $('body').on('click', ".selectedItem", function () {
      var value = $(this).data('value');
      console.log(value);
  });
```

But i just keep getting 'undefined'.  Any ideas of what i'm doing wrong?
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your event is on the `tr`, so `$(this)` is `tr`.

try to add the class `selectedItem` on the `td` ;)

```
 var target = $('#list');
 target.empty();
 for (var i = 0; i < myJson.length; i++) {
     $('<tr>')
         .append($('<td class = "selectedItem">', {
             'text': myJson[i].id,
             'data-value':myJson[i].id
         }))
         .append($('<td>', {
             'text': myJson[i].name
         }))
         .append($('<td>', {
             'text': myJson[i].Details
         }))
     .appendTo(target);
 };
```

You can also retrieve the first td if you keep the class on the tr :

```
var value = $(this).children().first().data('value');
```

Comment: +1 or maybe OP could use: `var value = $(this).find('td[data-value]').data('value');` and keeping class on TR level

Answer (score 2):

The `data-value` resides on the first table cell, whereas the class your targeting is on the row. In that case, you can get the `<td>` that has a `data-value` in the click event:

```
$('body').on('click', ".selectedItem", function () {
    var value = $(this).children('[data-value]').data('value');
    console.log(value);
});
```